# Calling function from VB.Net Class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Just wondering how I do this, Im creating a class that will have my common database functions. So for example I've created a function db_con in a class called db_functions.

How do i use that db_con function in for example my homepage vb code?

Do I import the class? I've tried typing the full class and method name, no joy so far?

Basic of the Basic questions I know :)

Comment: Can you put some code up for what you are doing.  You maybe want to read up on namespaces and statics for some of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You import the namespace, not the class.

It sounds like you have created a class in the same namespace.

You need to create an instance of `db_functions` and call your function

```
Dim func as New db_functions
func.db_con()
```

It sounds like you are trying to call `db_functions.db_con()`, to do this create your function as a `static` function with the `shared` keyword as below

```
Public Shared Function db_con() As ReturnType
  .....
  Return Value
End Function
```

If all your functions in that class are called that way and you never need an instance it should be a `static` class, in vb.net this is a `Module` (or therabouts).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I just learned :
lets say we have:

```
1-Module1
2-class1
3-class2
4-function1()
```

and you want to call the function to in `class2`:

1. If you create the function in the module as public, then you can call it just by the name:

   `function1()`

   that's what you write it in `class2` or any class in the project
2. If you create the function in `class1` and want to use it in `class2`, now we have two ways to declare the function in `class1`:

**A-** Public function1 (ByVal ---- as datatype ) as datatype
This make you have to create instance to use the function, like the follow:

```
dim ins as New class1
ins.function1()
```

that's what you write it in `class2` or any class in the project,

**B-** Public Shared function1 (`ByVal` ---- as datatype ) as datatype
this make you don't need to use the instanse when you call the function,like the follow:

```
class1.function1()
```

That's what you write it in `class2`
It works with me